# I want to read the content of a text file into a list in PIP

Tags: php

What I am doing is getting the content of a file in a list then according to the content of txt file I have created 3 variables name phnno and dob
the txt file looks like this

talha,04236522155,22/10/1990
Roshan,04235290600,08/11/1999

And my code looks like this

```
function read_file()
{
     $file_name=$GLOBALS['file_name'];

        $target="uploads/".$file_name;

        $myfile = fopen("$target", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

        while (!feof($myfile)) 
        {
            # code...
            $buffer=fgets($myfile,"4096");

            list($name,$cellphn,$dob)=explode(",",$buffer);

            $namearr=array($name);

            foreach ($namearr as $value) {
                # code...
                echo($value);
            }
        }
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

The output is talha Roshan
which is right but now I want to display only 1st name how should I do that and what if I only want to read phone numbers from the file store it in an array or list and then insert them into database?
So the crux is How should I access elements of my choice from this array?
How should I insert all or selected names in databse?
And how should I only ready phone numbers from the file

Comment: You said the directory is **F:\xampp\htdocs\proj\admin\uploads**. Not **upload**. I think, its the error. Check the variable $target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to remove the "admin/" and test again. As your F:\xampp\htdocs\proj\admin\index.php to call F:\xampp\htdocs\proj\admin\upload should be "upload/..."

EDIT: to be more specific, do this dirname(**FILE**)."/uploads/a.txt"

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you uploaded it to directory named "uploads" but your code has "upload"

```
$target="admin/upload/".$file_name;

Changing it to this may solve the problem if you didn't made any typo

$target="admin/uploads/".$file_name;
```

Comment: @ Netham i have changed it to uploads but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think your directory name is wrong in this case
`$target` should be admin/uploads instead of admin/upload